# Does XCTest methods generated dynamically by testInvocations work with xcodebuild's -only-testing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest, xcuitest

I have an app which needs to dynamically generate test methods in its `XCTestCase` subclass. I'm using `+(NSArray<NSInvocation*>*)testInvocations` to dynamically generate test methods at runtime with the following (dummy) names: `example_test`, `permissions_location_test` and `permissions_many_test`. Below is a simplified, ready-to-be-pasted-into-Xcode code.

```objectivec
@import XCTest;
@import ObjectiveC.runtime;

@interface ParametrizedTests : XCTestCase
@end

@implementation ParametrizedTests
+ (NSArray<NSInvocation *> *)testInvocations {
  NSLog(@"testInvocations() called");

  /* Prepare dummy input */
  __block NSMutableArray<NSString *> *dartTestFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [dartTestFiles addObject:@"example_test"];
  [dartTestFiles addObject:@"permissions_location_test"];
  [dartTestFiles addObject:@"permissions_many_test"];

  NSMutableArray<NSInvocation *> *invocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSLog(@"Before the loop, %lu elements in the array", (unsigned long)dartTestFiles.count);

  for (int i = 0; i < dartTestFiles.count; i++) {
    /* Step 1 */

    NSString *name = dartTestFiles[i];

    void (^anonymousFunc)(ParametrizedTests *) = ^(ParametrizedTests *instance) {
      NSLog(@"anonymousFunc called!");
    };

    IMP implementation = imp_implementationWithBlock(anonymousFunc);
    NSString *selectorStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name];
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorStr);
    class_addMethod(self, selector, implementation, "v@:");

    /* Step 2 */

    NSMethodSignature *signature = [self instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
    invocation.selector = selector;

    NSLog(@"RunnerUITests.testInvocations(): selectorStr = %@", selectorStr);

    [invocations addObject:invocation];
  }

  NSLog(@"After the loop");

  return invocations;
}

@end
```

I can run all these tests at once using:

```
xcodebuild test \
  -scheme Landmarks \
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 15'
```

Excerpt from above command's stdout:

```
Test Suite 'Selected tests' passed at 2023-11-16 13:44:59.148.
     Executed 3 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.246 (0.248) seconds
```

#### Problem

The problem I'm facing now is that I cannot select just one test to run using `xcodebuild`'s `-only-testing` flag. For example:

```
xcodebuild test \
  -scheme Landmarks \
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 15' \
  -only-testing 'LandmarksUITests/ParametrizedTests/example_test'
```

does not work - no tests are executed:

```
Test Suite 'ParametrizedTests' passed at 2023-11-16 13:45:58.472.
     Executed 0 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.000 (0.000) seconds
```

I also tried doing:

```
xcodebuild test \
  -scheme Landmarks \
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 15' \
  -only-testing 'LandmarksUITests/ParametrizedTests/testInvocations'
```

but the result is the same.

So the question is: **how can I select a subset of tests (that were generated dynamically at runtime using testInvocations) with the -only-testing option?**. Is is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, I found out that XCTest calls tests differently when `-only-testing MyTarget/MyClass/myTest` is passed. More specifically, the [`XCTestCase.defaultTestSuite`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496289-defaulttestsuite?language=objc) is not called when a single test is specified in `-only-testing`.

XCTest framework checks if it can run the test passed in `-only-testing` by sending a message to [`NSObject.instancesRespondToSelector:aSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418555-instancesrespondtoselector) (`XCTestCase` of course inherits from `NSObject`) and checking what it returns. This seemed like a good hook point to call `defaultTestSuite` manually, which in turn calls `testInvocations`, which generates and swizzles-in test methods to the `ParametrizedTests` class.

My `LandmarksTests` class was missing override of that selector. After I added it to my `ParametrizedTests` class:

```objectivec
+ (BOOL)instancesRespondToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
  [self defaultTestSuite]; // calls testInvocations
  BOOL result = [super instancesRespondToSelector:aSelector];
  return true;
}
```

it started working fine!

Here's the final file that can be copy-pasted into a file `ParametrizedTests.m` that is inside the `LandmarksUITests` UI Test Target and it works fine!

```objectivec
@import XCTest;
@import ObjectiveC.runtime;

@interface ParametrizedTests : XCTestCase
@end

@implementation ParametrizedTests

+ (BOOL)instancesRespondToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
  [self defaultTestSuite]; // calls testInvocations
  BOOL result = [super instancesRespondToSelector:aSelector];
  return true;
}

+ (NSArray<NSInvocation *> *)testInvocations {
  NSLog(@"testInvocations() called");

  /* Prepare dummy input */
  __block NSMutableArray<NSString *> *dartTestFiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [dartTestFiles addObject:@"example_test"];
  [dartTestFiles addObject:@"permissions_location_test"];
  [dartTestFiles addObject:@"permissions_many_test"];

  NSMutableArray<NSInvocation *> *invocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSLog(@"Before the loop, %lu elements in the array", (unsigned long)dartTestFiles.count);

  for (int i = 0; i < dartTestFiles.count; i++) {
    /* Step 1 */

    NSString *name = dartTestFiles[i];

    void (^anonymousFunc)(ParametrizedTests *) = ^(ParametrizedTests *instance) {
      NSLog(@"anonymousFunc called!");
    };

    IMP implementation = imp_implementationWithBlock(anonymousFunc);
    NSString *selectorStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name];
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorStr);
    class_addMethod(self, selector, implementation, "v@:");

    /* Step 2 */

    NSMethodSignature *signature = [self instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
    invocation.selector = selector;

    NSLog(@"RunnerUITests.testInvocations(): selectorStr = %@", selectorStr);

    [invocations addObject:invocation];
  }

  NSLog(@"After the loop");

  return invocations;
}

@end
```

See also:

- [how Quick framework overrides this method](https://github.com/Quick/Quick/blob/ef9aaf3f634b3a1ab6f54f1173fe2400b36e7cb8/Sources/Quick/QuickSpec.swift#L51-L65)